# My entered input is not showing in the resulted output

Tags: java, arrays, input, output, bufferedreader

My program is running properly.But if I enter a integer value from keyboard..then the output is not showing the entered values.This code is from my core java book and i have written it exactly like it was mentioned in the book. I'm a beginner in programming that's why I'm not able to find my mistake. Please guide me in this.

[This image is showing the exact output which I am getting by entering total number of subjects first and then marks obtained in each subjects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPx7e.jpg)

```
//Total marks and percentage
import java.io. * ;
class Arr2
{public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
     {
     //to accept data from keyboard
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new           InputStreamReader(System.in));
    
       //ask how many subjects 
      System.out.println("How many subjects?");
      int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
      
      //create 1D array with size n
      int[] marks = new int[n];
      
      //store elements into the array 
      for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
      {       System.out.println("Enter marks: ");
              marks[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine ());
                  }
      //find total marks 
      int tot= 0;
      for(int i =0; i<n; i++)
      tot +=  marks[i];
      //display total marks
      System.out.println("Total marks= "+tot);
      
      //find percentage
      float percent = (float)tot/n;
      System.out.println("Percentage="+ percent);
      
      }
}
```

I have checked my mistakes at every point but I couldn't find any of my mistakes. I have also Googled it but could not find it. Please help me in it.

Comment: why would your input values be shown in output? your output should show `tot` and `percent` as per the code. If you want your input to be shown as well, you should print that as well.

Comment: This code only display Total marks and percentage. Do you want to print input values also?

Answer (score 0):

Your code did not contain a print statement that displayed the entered values. In order to display values stored in an array you can either loop through it and display each value individually or you can use Arrays.toString() method which prints the entire array as a string.

```
   //Total marks and percentage
    import java.io.*;
    class Arr2 {
      public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    //to accept data from keyboard
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    //ask how many subjects 
    System.out.println("How many subjects?");
    int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    //create 1D array with size n
    int[] marks = new int[n];

    //store elements into the array 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter marks: ");
        marks[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    }
    //find total marks 
    int tot = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        tot += marks[I];
    
    // display input marks ------ Add the line below
    System.out.println("Entered marks= "+ Arrays.toString(marks));

    //display total marks
    System.out.println("Total marks= " + tot);

    //find percentage
    float percent = (float) tot / n;
    System.out.println("Percentage=" + percent);

 }
}
```

Comment: It is throwing an error and saying that it cannot find variable "Arrays"  to class named "arr2"

Answer (score 0):

The code given has print statements written for displaying only the `percentage` and `total marks`. If the requirement is to print the entered marks we will have to add an additional print statement.
For printing the input marks stored in the `marks` array we can either use:

- for loop, iterate through each of the element in `marks` array and print them
- Arrays.toString() method, which prints the `marks` array in String format.

Please find the revised version of the code:

```
import java.io. *;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Arr2{
   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
      
      //to accept data from keyboard
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    
      //ask how many subjects 
      System.out.println("How many subjects?");
      int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
      
      //create 1D array with size n
      int[] marks = new int[n];
      
      //store elements into the array 
      for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {       
         System.out.println("Enter marks: ");
         marks[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine ());
      }

      //find total marks 
      int tot = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
         tot +=  marks[i];

      //Display the entered marks
      System.out.print("Marks: ");
      /*
      //Using for-loop
      for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++){
         System.out.print(marks[i] + "\t");
      }
      */
      

      //Using Arrays.toString() method
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(marks));

      //display total marks
      System.out.println("Total marks = "+tot);
      
      //find percentage
      float percent = (float) tot / n;
      System.out.println("Percentage = "+ percent);
      
      }
}
```

**Output:**

```
How many subjects?
3
Enter marks: 
89
Enter marks: 
90
Enter marks: 
98
Marks: [89, 90, 98]
Total marks = 277
Percentage = 92.333336
```